# How to tell Linq which Database Version to use

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i am using sql server 2005 and I think Linq generating queries for a different database version. I got the query string that linq was producing and pasted the linq directly in SQL Server Management studio and it failed with many errors. But the query works well if Linq is used. Any ideas what could be going on. If linq needs to know what database version to use how do I do that?

Comment: Are you pasting SQL or LINQ into the management studio?

Comment: I put sql in the management studio not linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ will create a parameterized query.  You won't be able to directly copy the SQL into SSMS without adding definitions (and assigning values to) the parameters.